# out of memory for Java application

Tags: java

I'm creating a Java application for image processing , and after a while of working on this program I got Out of memory exception because I think the Image objects taking a lot of memory space ,I can save the images as files to hard disk and read them when i need but that may took milli-seconds vs Nano-seconds if I use RAM with object.what I can do to solve this?

Comment: the code is too big , but the idea is to read images from files and making objects from them and then allow user to make some image processing on them

Comment: Do you need all images loaded in RAM at the same time ? You can always fine tune the memory allocated to your program using the -Xmx flag. But if you keep all images in memory you'll always end up having memory issues

Comment: Im keeping images in memory for the fast feel of responding to the user action , as it can be slower if I will read the needed image from HD each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a memory profiler such as [`YourKit`](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) to figure out what it is exactly that's consuming the memory (for example, it could be due to the accidental retention of some unneeded references). Once you understand how your program is actually using the memory, you can formulate a plan of attack.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have issues with not disposing images you are not using.